# Launchpad commit messages

Tags: version-control, bazaar, launchpad

Is there any possibility to do some formatting of the commit messages from bazaar on launchpad? Something like what is in SVN+Redmine, e.g. using asterisks (*) and newlines to make lists or referencing or marking bugs fixed (like "fixes #866" and the bug with number #866 will be automatically marked fixed).

So does launchpad has this feature? If yes, where could I find some doc about it? I didn't find anything on launchpad (but maybe i didn't search enough).

Thanks for advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at commit option `--fixes`, it allows you to specify Launchpad (and some other sites) bug numbers in a machine readable format. Run `bzr help bugs` to get help on this topic.

I do not know if this is integrated well on the Launchpad side currently. I have not tried this feature. It should be easy to try out though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is currently available, but it should be possible to contribute this functionality to the upstream project: https://launchpad.net/loggerhead